# React Testing - TypeError: localStorage.getItem is not a function

Tags: reactjs, sinon, chai, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having trouble testing a react component that uses localstorage to save a JWT token and retrieves it for api calls and routing based on authentication.

The component itself works fine, but when i test, i'm getting this error in all the three tests

> TypeError: localStorage.getItem is not a function

Here is the code i have written

**home.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import Home from '../containers/Home.jsx';


describe('<Home />', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    global.localStorage = {
      i2x_token: 'someToken',
    };
  });

  it('renders without exploding', () => {
    shallow(<Home />);
  });

  it('renders children when passed in', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Home>
        <div className='unique' />
      </Home>,
   );
    expect(wrapper.contains(<div className='unique' />)).to.equal(true);
  });

  it('calls componentWillMount', () => {
    sinon.spy(Home.prototype, 'componentWillMount');
    const wrapper = mount(<Home />);

expect(Home.prototype.componentWillMount).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
    Home.prototype.componentWillMount.restore();
  });
});
```

**home.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Header from '../components/Header.jsx';
import Content from '../components/Content.jsx';

import { API_CONTENT } from '../utils/constants';
import request from '../utils/request';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: null,
    };
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('i2x_token');
    const requestURL = API_CONTENT;
    const requestObj = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
      }),
    };
    request(requestURL, requestObj).then((reply) => {
      if (reply.results.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ content: reply.results });
       } else {
        console.log('no reply from API');
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
     localStorage.removeItem('i2x_token');
     browserHistory.push('/');
   }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.content;
    if (data !== null) {
      return (
        <div className='container'>
          <Header logout={ this.logout } />
          <Content data={ this.state.content } />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Header logout={ this.logout } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localStorage` is part of your Browser which is not available in a unit test, you need to mock it. You can mock the necessary methods in the `localStorage` object:

**home.test.js**

```
beforeAll(() => {
   global.localStorage = {
      i2x_token: 'someToken',
      getItem: function () {
         return 'someToken'
      }
   };
});
....
```

Comment: You can also try to implement your own localStorage for unit tests and add it to global in some setup tests file or use sinon.spy (as you already did for componentWillMount) to mock the getItem function

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/sanusart/c1558845350cc8d8cafbe3c903d46afc

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and I resolved it by using the following: `"mock-local-storage": "^1.0.4"`. The package can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-local-storage).

This module mocks the *localStorage* and the *sessionStorage* for you, which was hustle free for me. The plug in allows you to add middleware to the store such as `redux-thunk` and `redux-sagas`.

N.B. I am using Mocha to run my tests.

For other frameworks you can use the following configuration

```
global.window = {}
import localStorage from 'mock-local-storage'
window.localStorage = global.localStorage
```